# virtual-burrito .bashrc entry

Tags: python, bash, wrapper, virtualenv

I installed virtual-burrito the python virtualenv creator. On rebooting I cannot restart virtual-burrito somehow my .bashrc entry for virtual-burrito is missing.

Does anyone know the format for the .bashrc entry for this?

I tried copying my pythonbrew entry but it is not the same also tried 
    source ~/.venvburrito/bin/virtualenv-burrito

but that did not resolve it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
source $HOME/.venvburrito/startup.sh
```